# Simple MDX Calculated Member

Tags: mdx

In my simple cube, I have a measure `= \[Measure\].\[Salary\]`, I have also `\[DimEmpployee\].\[EmployeeLastName\].\[Smith\].` I would like to create calculated measure, where I can display in Axis 0 two measures - `\[Measure\].\[Salary\]` and calculated measure `\[Measure\].\[SmithsSalaries\]`, to compare difference between Smith's earnings vs Total Salary.

[image]

I would like to compare Measure.SmithSalaries with other measures accross all diemensions. Is it possible to create such a measure using SCOPE statement?

I was playing around SCOPE statements, but it was displaying results only if DimEmployee was selected. I am looking for something which is running in blocks to avoid performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need a simple calculated measure.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SmithSalaries]
 AS ([DimEmployee].[EmployeeLastName].[Smith], [Measures].[Salary]), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

After that you can combine that with you total salary for example to get a ratio.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SmithSalaries Ratio]
 AS DIVIDE(([DimEmployee].[EmployeeLastName].[Smith], [Measures].[Salary]),[Measures].[Salary]) 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

SCOPE allows you to have different behaviors when different combinations of Dimensions are into play, like returning a different calculation when the DimEmployee is selected but otherwise just return the normal calculation. Like a Very efficient IF condition to check what are in the Axis of this calculation.